# Generate a list from a root word

Tags: python

I need to write a function in Python that takes in a root word and generates a list by adding a list of words  to the root word. i.e. `Input = juicy, list =apple,tomato, orange , Output = juicy apple, juicy tomato, juicy orange.` Advice please

```
def generate('word') 
  list  = ['a' ,' b', 'c', 'd']
```

....

```
 new list = [ 'word a', 'word b', 'word c', 'word d']
```

Comment: As a general rule make sure you add a few examples of things you tried for best results on Stack Overflow. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The function would be:

```py
def generate(root, words):
    return [root + ' ' + w for w in words]
```

Another solution is to use a lambda expression:

```py
generate = lambda root, words: [root + ' ' + w for w in words]
```

In both cases:

```py
>>> generate('juicy', ['apple', 'tomato', 'orange'])
['juicy apple', 'juicy tomato', 'juicy orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basic string formating + list comprehension

```
>>> root_word = 'juicy'
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> new_list = ['{} {}'.format(root_word, i) for i in my_list]
>>> print new_list
['juicy a', 'juicy b', 'juicy c', 'juicy d']
```

This is similar to the following:

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> for word in my_list:
...     new_word = '{} {}'.format(root_word, word)
...     # '{}' is a generic character to be formatted
...     # which in this case replaces root_word with the 
...     # first instance of '{}' and word with the second.
...     
...     my_list.append(word)
... print new_list
['juicy a', 'juicy b', 'juicy c', 'juicy d']
```

If you want to add this in a function, just define:

```
def join_words(root_word, my_list):
    return ['{} {}'.format(root_word, i) for i in my_list]
```

You should probably have the root word and the list BOTH as arguments in the function, since this generalizes the resulting code for you: you can pass your list to the function and generate different combo words as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do the list comprehension

```
def generate(word):
  list  = ['a' ,' b', 'c', 'd']
  return [word + ' ' + letter for letter in list]


print generate('word')
```